# Function for fetching data from API not being called inside useEffect in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, fetch

I am fetching data from API based on user Input. I am calling trainDetails() function from inside useEffect(). But on consoling inside trainDetails(), I find that control is never reaching there. Why is it happening and how to resolve it?

```
const [trainData, setTrainData] = useState("");

const location = useLocation();
const fromStation = location.state.fromS;
const toStation = location.state.toS;

async function trainDetails() {
    setLoading(true);
    console.log("Hello");
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://irctc1.p.rapidapi.com/api/v3/trainBetweenStations",
      params: {
        fromStationCode: `${fromStation}`,
        toStationCode: `${toStation}`,
        dateOfJourney: "2023-05-20",
      },
      headers: {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "{apiKey}",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "irctc1.p.rapidapi.com",
      },
    };

    const response = await axios.request(options);
    console.log(response.status);
    if (!response.ok) {
      console.log(response.data.data);
      setTrainData(response.data);
      //console.log("Data is" + trainData);
    } else {
      console.log(response.status);
    }
  }

useEffect(() => {
    trainDetails();
  }, []);

return (
    <div>
      {/* {!currentUser ? <Navbar /> : <LoginNavBar />} */}
      {!currentUser && <Navbar />}
      {currentUser && <LoginNavBar />}

      <div className="train-list">
        <h1>
          Train is running from {fromStation} to {toStation}
        </h1>
        {/*  {console.log(trainData)} */}
        {trainData.data.map((train) => {
          return (
            <div className="train-container">
              <Box>
                <Card train={train} />
              </Box>
              <div className="btn">
                <Button
                >
                  Book
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        {/* <Card train={data} /> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the error being displayed: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
console.log("Hello") is not printed.

Comment: Wrap the async code in a try...catch and you'll catch some errors hopefully! It could be a network error.

Comment: Also, trainData is an empty string initially. You can't map over it. A quick fix would be `trainData?.data?.map`.

Comment: initialize use state like this `const [trainData, setTrainData] = React.useState({ data: [] })`